# A question about notation issues with *homogeneous* polynomials

Tags: polynomials, invariant-theory

Reading about *homogeneous* polynomials in an [introduction to invariant theory](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1072746/FULLTEXT01.pdf), I'm trying to better understand some notation. In particular, every homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ can be written as

$$f =\sum_{|\alpha|=d}a_\alpha x^\alpha ,$$

where $\alpha= (\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n) \in \mathbb{N}^n$, $a_{\alpha} \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x^{\alpha}:=x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$. Now what does it exactly mean to take the sum over $|\alpha|=d$? is it just an abbreviation for saying that we take the sum over $\alpha$ such that the condition holds? Also by replacing the definition of $x^\alpha$ in the above equation what I obtain is:

$$f =\sum_{\alpha_1 + \dots + \alpha_n=d}a_{\alpha_1} x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots a_{\alpha_n}x_n^{\alpha_n}$$

but I'm not really sure about how to provide examples and say what is what.

Comment: Take $n=3$ and $d=2$ for example, then you would have $x_1^2$, $x_2^2$, $x_3^2$, $x_1 x_2$, $x_1 x_3$ and $x_2 x_3$ as the monomials in your sum. The powers all total $2$

Comment: But I do not have all the monomials necessarily in the sum right? basically we can set some to zero by choosing $a_\alpha=0$?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @JamesArten Also, $\,a_\alpha\,$ is one single coefficient. There is no point (and no unique way) to break it down into $\,a_{\alpha_1} a_{\alpha_2}\dots a_{\alpha_n}\,$.